# Oracle: Return the specific records based on one column date

Tags: oracle

I have a database structure as below.

| period | month | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | April | 2022-04-01 |
| 2 | May | 2022-05-07 |
| 3 | June | 2022-06-04 |
| 4 | July | 2022-07-02 |
| 5 | August | 2022-08-06 |
| 6 | September | 2022-09-03 |
| 7 | October | 2022-10-01 |
| 8 | November | 2022-11-05 |
| 9 | December | 2022-12-03 |
| 10 | January | 2023-01-01 |
| 11 | February | 2023-02-04 |
| 12 | March | 2023-03-04 |

End date of the year is 2023-03-31.

Based on current_date, how do I select the query to return where the current date falls under Period 6.

My current query as below.

```
SELECT period FROM table1 as a
WHERE
a.start_date = (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM table1 as b WHERE 
b.start_date <=current_date) and ROWNUM <= 1
```

Is there anyway to improve the current query which to avoid using subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Today is September 22nd, so - would this do?

Some sample data:

```
SQL> with test (period, month, start_date) as
  2    (select  1, 'april'    , date '2022-04-01' from dual union all
  3     select  5, 'august'   , date '2022-08-06' from dual union all
  4     select  6, 'september', date '2022-09-03' from dual union all
  5     select  7, 'october'  , date '2022-10-01' from dual union all
  6     select 10, 'january'  , date '2023-01-01' from dual union all
  7     select 12, 'march'    , date '2023-03-04' from dual
  8    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select period, month, start_date,
 11       row_number() over (order by start_date desc) rn
 12     from test
 13     where start_date <= sysdate
 14    )
 15  select period
 16  from temp
 17  where rn = 1
 18   /

    PERIOD
----------
         6

SQL>
```

It *still* uses a subquery (or a CTE, as in my example), but - as opposed to your approach, it selects from the source table only once, so performance should be improved.

---

A few more tests: instead of `sysdate` (line #13), presume that today is September 2nd (which means that it is in period #5):

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select period, month, start_date,
 11       row_number() over (order by start_date desc) rn
 12     from test
 13     where start_date <= date '2022-09-02'
 14    )
 15  select period
 16  from temp
 17  where rn = 1;

    PERIOD
----------
         5

SQL>
```

Or, if today were August 7th:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select period, month, start_date,
 11       row_number() over (order by start_date desc) rn
 12     from test
 13     where start_date <= date '2022-08-07'
 14    )
 15  select period
 16  from temp
 17  where rn = 1;

    PERIOD
----------
         5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule for the `start_date` appears to be:

- If the month is January (first month of the calendar year) or April (typically, first month of the financial year) then use the 1st of that month;
- Otherwise use the 1st Saturday of the month.

If that is the case then you can calculate the start date of the next month and use the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  start_date <= SYSDATE
AND    SYSDATE < CASE
                 WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1))
                      IN (1, 4) -- 1st month of calendar or financial year
                 THEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1), 'MM')
                 ELSE NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1), 'MM') - 1, 'SATURDAY')
                 END
```

Then, for your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  period     NUMBER(2,0),
  month      VARCHAR2(9)
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
               CAST(
                 TO_CHAR(start_date, 'FXMonth', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
                 AS VARCHAR2(9)
               )
             ),
  start_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO table1 (period, start_date)
  SELECT LEVEL,
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-01', LEVEL - 1))
              IN (1, 4) -- 1st month of calendar or financial year
         THEN ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-01', LEVEL - 1)
         ELSE NEXT_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2022-04-01', LEVEL - 1) - 1, 'SATURDAY')
         END
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
```

Outputs:

| PERIOD | MONTH | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | September | 2022-09-03 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H5HNHcv4)

Comment: I have an issue if my date = '2023-04-01', I should not getting any record. But when i try run this query, it still return to period 12.

Comment: @Junie Fixed. Added `'MM'` to the truncate.